# mouse wheel does not work, select2 and jQuery custom content scroller

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrollbar, jquery-select2

I combined select2 and jQuery custom content scroller libraries to get a nice, functional dropdown but for some reason I can't make it work on mouse wheel.

here is a simple code for loading components, I tried different approach as well as built in options but no luck so far

```
$('#testDropdown').select2();

$("span.select2-selection").on("click", function () {
    $(".select2-results").toggleClass("mCustomScrollbar").attr('data-mcs-theme', 'gray-theme');
    $(".select2-results").mCustomScrollbar("destroy");
    $(".select2-results").mCustomScrollbar({
      advanced: {
        updateOnContentResize: true
      }, 
      live: true,
      mouseWheel:true,    
      scrollInertia: 500
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rpddg05c/2/)

any pointers would be appreciated